# Why pass variables to a class instead of method

Tags: php, oop

I was wondering what is the benefit of passing parameters to a class rather than to a method.

In terms of code, what's the benefit of doing this:

```
$books = new Books($book_id, $book_name);
```

instead of

```
$books = new Books;
$books->setBook($book_id, $book_name);
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is highly context-dependent.

Comment: This is passing arguments to a method, to the __construct() method

Comment: Would you be able to give some examples?

Comment: What's the benefit of eating a soup with one spoon, not two?

Comment: [PHP Constructors and Destructors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

Comment: @YourCommonSense Lasts longer?

Comment: It's wrong to close this question as "primarily opinion based". There are well understood, long established recognized best practices and engineering principles strongly in favour of the first approach. It is not a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 6):

"Passing to a class" is not a thing. `new Foo($bar, $baz)` is instantiating a new object and is passing parameters to the *constructor method*:

```
class Foo {

    public function __construct($bar, $baz) {
        ...
    }

}
```

There's no difference as such between passing parameters to a regular method and to the constructor. The only difference is that the constructor is called when an object is instantiated, and other methods are called anytime later.

You should pass parameters to the constructor which the object requires at construction time. Typically this means you pass parameters which are required for the object to work at all. The constructor can throw an exception if it doesn't like the parameters, which means the object will fail to instantiate at all. This guarantees that the object is in a known, consistent state. Compare:

```
$api = new FooAPI($id, $password);
$api->doSomething();

$api = new FooAPI;
// $api->setId($id);
// $api->setPassword($password);
$api->doSomething();  // Error! No id and password given
```

Answer (score 1):

While @deceze answer covers the major facts, I'd like to additionally state one of the most crucial point - perhaps emphasizing

paraphrasing from [here](http://ralphschindler.com/2012/03/09/php-constructor-best-practices-and-the-prototype-pattern)

> Each concrete object would have a constructor with a signature which
>   represents how a consumer should fully instantiate the object.

Answer (score 0):

if you will see the assembly code of same code snippet which u have giv en you ll notice it increases around 5-6 instruction so it depends if you which method u want to prefer.but generally the first one is prefered if you know the values for instance variables while creating the object else the second one is prefered as it saves load of 5-6 instructions on processor.i have written the both code snippets in c++ and analysed their assembly code.

Comment: I'd think the efficiency plays second or third fiddle way behind the logical code structure here. In practice you should never ever prefer one way over the other based on a difference of 5 or 6 CPU instructions.